# AngularJS can't share data between controllers using factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I tried sharing data between two controllers using a factory. For some reason, the two inputs don't share data. In the **AppCtrl** controller I assign  `Data.FirstName` to equal `lattitude`. But when I get to the **PathController**, I can't read the value stored in `Data.FirstName`.
Can anyone let me know what is wrong with my code?

```
 .factory('Data', function(){
   return { FirstName: 'jjjj' };
})


          // controller one
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, Data, $http, $ionicModal, $timeout) {
     ....
 $scope.mapLocation = function(lattitude, longittude) {

    Data.FirstName = lattitude;
    $scope.Data = Data;
 }
    ....
})


          // controller two
.controller("PathController", [ '$scope', function($scope, Data) {

 $scope.Data = Data;
 console.log(Data.FirstName); // Not getting Data.FirstName

    angular.extend($scope, {
        center: {
         lat: 35.720031000963,
        lng: -87.343068987131,
        zoom: 17
        },
        markers: {
          Campus: {
             lat: 35.728031000963,
             lng: -87.343068987131,
             focus: true,
             draggable: false,
             message: "Building1"
          },
        },
        defaults: {
            scrollWheelZoom: false
        }
    });
}])
```

Comment: Are you calling mapLocation anywhere? Can you show where?

Comment: You have to use an object type in $scope if you want to inherit a property from global scope.To understand clearly please read more at here [Understanding-Scopes][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 1):

change the data factory like this

```
.factory('Data', function(){
   return { 
       mydata: {
              FirstName: 'jjjj'
            }

 };
})
```

and assign
as follows

```
Data.mydata.FirstName = lattitude;
$scope.Data = Data.mydata;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add the `factory` as parameter. Try this

`.controller("PathController", [ '$scope', function($scope, Data) {`

Comment: It should be `.controller("PathController", [ '$scope', 'Data', function($scope, Data) {`, please fix it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but try this:

```
.service('Data', function(){
    var FirstName = 'jjjj';
    return { FirstName: FirstName };
})
```